# Definindo a cor de uma div em rgb

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estou fazendo uma div, onde ao clicar ela fica laranja, e ao clicar novamente, ela volta a ficar branca.

Porém tenho duas perguntas :

1. Ao comparar a cor com rgb na parte 
   `if(document.getElementById('homem').style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(#FF6600)')`
   ou 
   `if(document.getElementById('homem').style.backgroundColor == '#FF6600')`

   Não dá certo pois ela não volta a ficar branca. Onde estou errando?
2. Esta é a melhor maneira de codificar a alternação de cores em click?

```js
function selecionaGeneroH(){
  // #FF6600
  if(document.getElementById('homem').style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(#FF6600)'){
   document.getElementById('homem').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
   document.getElementById('homem').style.color = 'grey'; 
   document.getElementById('homem').style.border = '4px solid #FF6600';     
  } else { 
   document.getElementById('homem').style.backgroundColor = '#FF6600';
   document.getElementById('homem').style.color = 'white';
   document.getElementById('homem').style.border = '4px solid white';
 }
}

function selecionaGeneroM(){
  if(document.getElementById('mulher').style.backgroundColor == 'orange'){
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.color = 'grey'; 
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.border = '4px solid #FF6600';     
  } else { 
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.color = 'white';
   document.getElementById('mulher').style.border = '4px solid white';
 }
}
```

```css
#mulher { 
  float:left;
  width:151px;
  height:42px;
  border:4px solid #FF6600;
  color: grey;
  display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
  /* Códigos para que o texto não seja selecionado */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#homem {
  margin:0px 10px;
  float:left;
  width:151px;
  height:42px;
  border:4px solid #FF6600;
  color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 40px;
  /* Códigos para que o texto não seja selecionado */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-se
```

```html
<html> 
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="mulher" id="mulher" onclick="selecionaGeneroM()"> MULHERES</div></td>
      <td><div class="homem" id="homem" onclick="selecionaGeneroH()"> HOMENS</div></td>
    </tr>
    <br /><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) O seu código está fazendo a comparação `backgroundColor == 'rgb(#FF6600)'` mas o valor do background color é `rgb(255, 102, 0)`

2) Você pode fazer utilizando uma classe que muda o estilo padrão. Assim você habilita ou desabilita a classe ao clicar.
Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function selecionaGeneroH(){
    document.getElementById('homem').classList.toggle('ativo');
}

function selecionaGeneroM(){
    document.getElementById('mulher').classList.toggle('ativo');
}
```

```css
#mulher { 
  float:left;
  width:151px;
  height:42px;
  border:4px solid #FF6600;
  color: grey;
  display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
  /* Códigos para que o texto não seja selecionado */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  
    /* Estilo normal */
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  border: 4px solid #FF6600';
}

#homem {
  margin:0px 10px;
  float:left;
  width:151px;
  height:42px;
  border:4px solid #FF6600;
  color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 40px;
  /* Códigos para que o texto não seja selecionado */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  
  /* Estilo normal */
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  border: 4px solid #FF6600;
 }
 
 #homem.ativo {
  background-color: #FF6600;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid white;
 }
 
 #mulher.ativo {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid white;
 }
```

```html
<html> 
 <body>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="mulher" id="mulher" class="ativo" onclick="selecionaGeneroM()"> MULHERES</div></td>
        <td><div class="homem" id="homem" class="ativo" onclick="selecionaGeneroH()"> HOMENS</div></td>
  </tr>
  <br /><br />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aaaah, entendi !! muito obrigado pela explicação @André, foi de ótima ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você está setando a cor com `'orange'` e comparando com `'rgb(#FF6600)'` tem que comparar com o mesmo valor que setou.

O melhor é usar uma `variável` ou um `checkbox`(o mais utilizado).

Comment: No homem eu  defino '(#FF6600)' e o comparo e não vai. O da mulher sim eu seto orange e dá certo